# Not able to build project using Maven

Tags: java, maven

I've two maven projects one is for Java services and one for Web. First I have built services project and the build was success using Maven clean install. When I try to build web project, the build is failing.

Here is the log

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project com.bb.Helloworld-web: Could not resolve
dependencies for project com.bb.Helloworld-web:com.bb.Helloworld-web:jar:1.1.1 BUILD-SNAPSHOT:
Failed to collect dependencies at com.extension.helloworld:com.extension.helloworld:jar:1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.extension.helloworld:com.extension.helloworld:jar:1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT:
Could not transfer artifact com.extension.helloworld:com.extension.helloworld:pom:1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
from/to spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

The services project has succesfully created JAR.

This is the dependency available in pom.xml of web

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.extension.helloworld</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.extension.helloworld</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version></dependency>
```

Please let me know if I'm missing anything

Comment: is that the whole xml?
<dependency> tag isn't closed for one, add </dependency> at the end

Comment: When you say "the build was success", you package or install? it's not the same; dependencies were collected first in .m2 file then if not found in repository.

Comment: Updated @TaaviKivimaa

Comment: @Ehcnalb, I mean maven clean install

Comment: `Could not transfer artifact com.extension.helloworld:com.extension.helloworld:pom:1.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` 
did really dep. with given artifact ID and group ID exists in your repository? :) usually its something like `com.extension:helloworld` where `com.extension` is a groupID and `helloworld` artifactID

Answer (score 1):

There was one typo. There should be com.bb.extension.helloworld instead of com.extension.helloworld. Thanks for your help

Comment: You really need to post the entire pom.xml rather than just a snippet

Comment: If the only problem was a typo, you may as well delete your question. There is no future value for anyone else here.